# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined - mongoose, express, nodeJS, ejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

How would I go about getting the name of the user from an object ID? Im currently using populate to pull the user data from one schema to another and it's returning both the user ID and the name however I just want the name to show up. I have tried using post.submittedby.name in the view however I keep receiving a 'name is undefined' error. I have also tried to set it to a variable but same error.

Below is how my data is displaying on the page.

[image: Here is how the info is showing, would like to extract just the name.]

Ideally I would like it to say Posted By: user2

Documents below

**Post model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true,
    },
    submittedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User',
    },
    comments: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Other info goes here',
    }
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

**User model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**index.js**

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .populate({ path: 'submittedBy', select: 'name' })
    .then((result) => {
      res.render('dashboard', {
        posts: result,
        user: req.user,
      })
      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })

})
```

**Home page/dashboard view.ejs**

```
        <div class="forumView">
            <h2>All Posts</h2>

            <% if (posts.length > 0)  {%>
            <% posts.forEach(post => { %>

                <h3 class="title"> <%= post.title %></h3>
                <p class="body"> <%= post.body %> </p>
                <p class="body"> Posted by: <%= post.submittedBy %> </p>

            <% }) %>
            <% } else { %>
                <p>There are no posts to display...</p>  
                <% } %>  
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening is when you pass results down to the template, those `submittedBy` subdocuments are converted into strings. So try this:

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .populate({ path: 'submittedBy', select: 'name' })
    .lean() // <- This will give you plain JSON objects as opposed to mongoose docs.
    .then((result) => {
      result.forEach(i => i.submittedBy = i.submittedBy.name) // <- This will override the submittedBy prop with the actual name vs an object
      res.render('dashboard', {
        posts: result,
        user: req.user,
      })
      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

After this, no changes to the template code are necessary.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried this way and received the same error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Would you recommend another way to pulling the users name for these posts? I'm only using populate as it's what I've seen recommended by others

Comment: @kl Did you get it on this line this time: `results.forEach(i => i.submittedBy = i.submittedBy.name)` or did you get it in the ejs file? Your esj file should still have this `<%= post.submittedBy %>`

Comment: I got it on the console, my ejs file won't even load.

Comment: @kl There is a typo in my code `results.forEach(i =>...` should be `result.forEach(i =>...`. Can you make sure that part is right in your code?

Comment: yup i caught that and changed it already... seems like it's still not taking the .name for submitted by

Comment: Can you replace `result.forEach(i =>...` line with `console.log(result)`? I just wanna see what the docs look like. If there are too many results, just put `limit(1)` before `lean()`.

Comment: Here you go 

  {
    _id: 6033dd267a4f4b2e18550a75,
    comments: 'Other info goes here',
    title: 'test',
    body: 'test test test',
    submittedBy: { _id: 6032df9b9802684640e33d40, name: 'user 2' },
    date: 2021-02-22T16:34:46.131Z,
    __v: 0
  }

Comment: I'm stumped. Looks perfectly right. I guess the last thing I would ask is to make sure you have the `lean()` before `then()`, but it seems you already do.

Comment: yup it's after the lean, I really appreciate the time you took to look into it, I'll keep researching

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: your code was correct, just had to move .lean before .populate! Thank you again!

Comment: @kl Oh wow. Great to know you figured it out.